# appConfig:28 Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, vite, amazon-cloudfront, astrojs

I'm running into some issues with my app after it was deployed.

My app is a parent Astro shell serving up multiple React JS child apps. Vite is used for build. The child apps are all deployed independently, and then served by the parent Astro shell.

All apps files are put onto S3 bucket and then deployed to Cloudfront distributions. The set-up looks like:
(1) One parent Gitlab -> One parent S3 bucket -> Parent Cloudfront Distribution
(2) 4 seperate child Gitlabs -> One child S3 bucket -> One Child Cloudfront Distribution
The Parent Cloudfront Distribution serves up the Child Cloudfront

Originally, everything works great. However, when I try to access my Cloudfront-deployed app, I get these error messages :

```
Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
```

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch dynamically imported module: https://d2fskyt0z4zbx.cloudfront.net/_astro/ConfigHeader.8694473f.
```

If it helps, this is what the S3 bucket looks like for the parent Astro app:
[Parent App S3 bucket files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVodC.png)

The _astro folder that the error is throwing about, partly looks like this:
[_astro folder files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkrE0.png)

Does anyone know how I could fix the two errors?

I have tried changing this line in all the index.html:

```
    <script type="text" src="src/main.jsx"></script>
```

to

```
    <script type="module" src="src/main.jsx"></script>
```

and also making sure this says "module"

[package.json type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfTvQ.png)

Please let me know how you think i could fix the two errors. As stated, after deploying to Cloudfront, it was working fine. A week later, meaning now, is when it started throwing the two errors above